# How do I highlight the squares adjacent to my player in a Isometric grid

Tags: unity, gui, rpg, isometric, grid

I am making a grid base RPG (like Fire Emblem but isometric) but currently I'm stuck on the movement, mainly the UI (showing how far the player can move around the board).

Like the image below where the person can go is highlighted in a blue square

[image]

Stuff I have done so far:

1. made the grid 5x5 isometric and learn and code a pathfinding system
2. made a battle system that set up the starting stuff (like starting spot, turn order, and teams)
3. two characters one player, one enemy with basic info (like health, mp, and speed)
4. and set up the UI for buttons and the sprites for the highlighted boxes

[image: what it looks]

[image: the grid showing]

So this is where I am at and don't know where to go for the moving part.

This is what I am think might work for a solution:

- the grid is the pathfinding grid so change it to a grid of gameObject and add a characters to it (but still don't know about the UI)

Comment: [Have you reviewed past Q&A on drawing a movement range on a tile-based map](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=movement+range)?

Comment: going to see it now